# Getting information for this same day of the week in previous years

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure this is even possible without using PHP, but I'd love to try.

I have a database that looks like this (a bunch of other stuff, but this is all that is relevant:

`Date_Day` (is a range from 1 to 31 with no trailing 0)

`Date_Month` (is a range from January to December, not numerical)

`Date_Year` (is the year in 4 digit format, ex: 2005)

`Total` (number with 2 decimal places)

I know the way the dates are stored is awful, but this is the database I was given. If there is a query that I could use these columns to create an actual DATETIME column, I would happily do it, I just don't know what that query looks like.

I have this query that returns the Total sales amount for this day for all previous years:

```
SELECT 
    Date_Year, Date_Month, SUM(Total) 
FROM 
    tablename 
WHERE 
    Date_Year < YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND 
    Date_Month = MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) 
AND 
    Date_Day = DAY(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY 
    Date_Year, Date_Month
```

Example: If I run this today, I get the daily totals for October 4th for all previous years. The issue is that in sales, this isn't very helpful for comparing growth. What I really need is the daily totals for the 1st Friday in October for all previous years.

Is this possible without having to rely on PHP?

I found this based on TSQL, but I don't know the differences in syntax or even if it would work the same.

Comment: What if there is no sale in the 1st Friday of October in a previous year? What would you expect the query to return?

Comment: http://sqllessons.com/second_tuesday_of_the_month.html

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer, you could use a combination of concatenation, conversion, and CHARINDEX to turn those three fields into one date field.  I know t-sql and I know that mysql is a bit different.  I have a feeling that mysql has a CONCATENATE function instead of just sticking things together using a plus sign.  Perhaps someone else could comment on that part.  But if I were doing this in t-sql I'd do something like this to get a date (in US-Eng timezone):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CHARINDEX(LEFT(Date_Month,3),'XXJANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC')/3 as varchar(2))
    + '/' + CAST(Date_Day as varchar(2)) 
    + '/' + CAST(Date_Year as varchar(4)) as date)
FROM tablename
```

Yeah, it wouldn't be the fastest thing.  But it would work.  Then you could use normal datetime functions like DATEADD to get the range you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your current columns into a `DATE` column using [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) with the relevant [format string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
ALTER TABLE Sales ADD Date_Type DATE;

UPDATE Sales
SET Date_Type = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Date_Year,Date_Month,Date_Day), '%Y%M%e');
```

I'm not sure there is a particularly clean way to `SELECT` sales from the first friday of the month, but it can certainly be done. The way I came up with checks what day of the week the first of the month is, and then adds the necessary number of days to reach the following friday - then checks the date of the sales record against that.

```
SET @Month = MONTH(CURDATE());
SET @MMDD  = CONCAT('-',@Month,'-01');

SELECT * 
FROM Sales
WHERE Date_Type = 
        DATE_ADD(CONCAT(YEAR(Date_Type),@MMDD), INTERVAL
            CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CONCAT(YEAR(Date_Type),@MMDD)) = 7 
                 THEN 7 ELSE 0 
            END 
            + 6 - DAYOFWEEK(CONCAT(YEAR(Date_Type),@MMDD)) DAY);
```

[`DAYOFWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) returns 1 to 7 (Sunday to Saturday). So from the first of the month you can add 6 days, then subtract the `DAYOFWEEK` to give you the the following Friday - however if the 1st is a Saturday this would return the last day of the previous month so we need to add 7 days in that case.

[Example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/889c4c/64/0) (has an alternate version of the above query as well)

Comment: And it took me until the very last minute when I clocked that your example used `CURDATE()` and dates in October to realised this question is months old.....

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but you could generate a second table with a schema like:

```
Date_Day
Date_Month
Date_Year
Day_of_Week
Month_Dow_Counter
```

where an example row would be...

```
(13, 1, 2014, 'Monday', 2)
```

since today is the 2nd Monday of January. Then, you could query this table by the the `Day_of_Week` and `Month_Dow_Counter` (come up with a better name) to get back the Day/Month/Year and then join on your other table.